# Telethon receive location from user

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

What is a proper way to listen to "send location" messages from the user? My solution is to filter out messages by type of their media (`process_location`):

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=commands('/start')))
async def send_welcome(event: events.NewMessage.Event):
    await event.respond("Hello, I'm your helper bot!", buttons=[
        Button.request_location('Send location to detect timezone', resize=True),
    ])


@bot.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda e: isinstance(e.media, MessageMediaGeo)))
async def process_location(event: events.NewMessage.Event):
    geo_data = event.media
    ...
```

But is there a better way to distinguish location messages? Couldn't find it in the [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Your current way is fine, although the `isinstance` check can be simplified to `e.geo`.

Comment: @Lonami That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. You can compile this into an answer, I will accept it. Think it can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lonami suggested, I used `e.geo`:

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda e: e.geo))
async def process_location(event: events.NewMessage.Event):
    geo_data = event.media
    ...
```